# printing integers on different lines and with a word from text file, replacing the numbers that are divisible by 3

Tags: python, string, if-statement, input, integer

I have this problem where im absolutely losing mind over. I cant figure out how to get my code look like the example on the bottom. does anyone have any tips or corrections to my code? Im new to coding and this is all i can understand right now.

**This is my txt file:**

```
Python
Kobra
Anakonda
Mamba
Kyy
```

**this is my code**

```
import random
with open ('sanat.txt', encoding='utf-8') as f:
  sanat = f.readlines()
  
i=0

while True:

  maara=int(input("How many rounds?:"))
  sana1=random.choice(sanat).strip()
  sana2=random.choice(sanat).strip()
  output = str(i)
    
  for round in range(1, maara + 1):
    
    if round % 3 == 0:
      print(sana1)
    
    elif round % 5 == 0:
      print(sana2)
    
    elif round % 3 == 0 and round % 5 == 0:
      print(sana1 + sana2)
      
  else: print(round)
```

**this is the outcome:**

```
How many rounds?:6
Mamba
Kobra
Mamba
6
How many rounds?:7
Kobra
Kyy
Kobra
7
How many rounds?:8
Mamba
Python
Mamba
8
How many rounds?:4
Python
4
How many rounds?:
```

**And I need this code to get printed out like this. **

```
How many rounds?: 0
How many rounds?: -1
How many rounds?: 16
1
2
Foo
4
Python
qux
7
8
foo
bar
11
Bar
13
14
QuxFoo
16
How many rounds?:
'''
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error with your indenting and you have hit a quirk in Python syntax.

```
  # For-loop indentation level
  for round in range(1, maara + 1):

    # If-else indentation level
    if round % 3 == 0:
      print(sana1)

    elif round % 5 == 0:
      print(sana2)

    elif round % 3 == 0 and round % 5 == 0:
      print(sana1 + sana2)
  
  # THIS else should be indented two spaces more
  else: print(round)
```

With the current implementation, the `else` is matched with the `for`-loop, not the `if`-`elif` -sequence you have most likely wanted it to attach to.

The quirk is that Python allows for an `else`-statement for a `for`-loop. Not many programming languages have that and they would've raised an error.